# iPod 4G iOs 6.1.3 Ubuntu 12.04 sync?

Tags: 12.04, sync, vaio, ipod

I already installed Ubuntu 12.04 dualboot on my brandnew Vaio Windows 8 and it doesn't boot any more to windows, so I have a vaio laptop with ubuntu, a thing I can accept but it is impossible to sync the ipod touch 4g iOs 6.1.3 so it (the ipod) became almost useless cus once I tryed to sync with rhytmbox itunes don't recogniz'it any more and the music tracks dont play anymore.

Could anybody help me with this issue?

Comment: It sounds like you're having two issues:

1.  You can no longer actually 'dualboot' into Windows OR Ubuntu (only Ubuntu).  If this is correct, look into doing a boot-repair, because...
2.  There's no iTunes client that allows you to 'sync' your iOS device easily to Apple's iTunes functionality.  Sure, there's ways to get your music on your PC, but I think you need to fix #1 realistically.

Comment: Check this article out: http://www.d2clic.com/blog/linux/gestionar-ipod-con-ubuntu-12-04/#.Ubyuo85Dt0w Regards

Answer (score 0):

If you have your Windows 8 installation disk, insert this and reboot the computer, when asked what you want to do click repair and follow the instructions.

I hold my hands up now and say that I have never run Windows 8, so I don't necesarily know what I'm talking about!

On windows 7 I deleted my Boot manager by mistake, and was unable to load anything but Ubuntu however after reinstalling the Boot manager, I restarted and all now runs as it should.

Answer (score 0):

You have to recover access to the windows partition, beware of synchronizing the iPod in any linux distro, mos of the times it works but if you do it once with linux (rythmbox, banshee, amarok, clementine, etc.) and the next one in iTunes and so on, you'll end up messing the iPod and may need to do a master reset on it (return to factory settings) and lose all your info from the iPod. My suggestion is to only synch it with iTunes, so you avoid further complications.